# How do I return plain text for an AJAX query?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, single-page-application

I'm basing my knowledge on how to do this [on this Crunchify tutorial](http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/).

I have a single page application.

It has two functions. It needs to either send a request to the HTTP servlet, which will go call its own java, and from which it will recieve a JSON string containing any errors/advising the servlet what to do next.

The other function is that it prompts a save file dialog from the servlet.

The question is - how can I structure my servlet such that it returns a plain text HTTP response for the AJAX query to examine.

I have a very round about way of doing this, and I'd like a suggestion for how to achieve the same thing in a simpler manner.

**web.xml**

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/submitQuery</url-pattern>     
          <url-pattern>/saveFile
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**MyServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="world.hello.myservlets" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**MyServlet.java**

```
package world.hello.myservlets;

@Controller
public class MyServlet{


    @RequestMapping("/submitQuery")
    public ModelAndView submitQuery()
    {       

        return new ModelAndView("text", "model", "hello world");
    }

}
```

**/WEB-INF/jsp/text.jsp**

```
{model}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myAjax()
{
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
                /*do something with the http response*/
            }     

          }


     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "submitQuery", true);
     xml.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myAjax()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My understanding is the way this works is when the `/submitQuery` URI is sent, it's mapped to the `MyServlet` servlet. The servlet then returns a `ModelAndView` of `ViewName = text, ModelName = model`.

The dispatcher then redirects to /jsp/text.jsp (the specified view), displays the model on it. That final rendered output is returned to the AJAX object which can then access it how it wants.

Is there a more straight forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 11):

Yes there is more straight way for doing this.

As per [crunchify](http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/) tutorial you are returning the `ModelAndView` object. So that's the reason you are getting model object on `text.jsp`

```
ModelAndView: It returning both model and view information from a controller. Holder for both Model and View in the web MVC framework. Note that these are entirely distinct. This class merely holds both to make it possible for a controller to return both model and view in a single return value.
```

[More about ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html)

Now come to the other way in which you need to return plain text.

Annotate your `submitQuery()` method in controller with `@ResponseBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitQuery")
@ResponseBody
public String submitQuery() {
    return "Response";
}
```

> The `@ResponseBody` can be put on a method and indicates that the return
>   type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not
>   placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name)

Access the parameter in javascript.

```
function myAjax()
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "submitQuery", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I don't think `window.location.href = "your url"` is necessary. He's not actually looking to redirect, he's just looking to get the response text.

Comment: I read it multiple times. The word redirect is a byproduct of his misunderstanding of how JSP rendering works: "The dispatcher then redirects to /jsp/text.jsp (the specified view), displays the model on it. That final rendered output is returned to the AJAX object which can then access it how it wants."

Comment: There should be absolutely no redirect logic; his question clearly states: "The question is - how can I structure my servlet such that it returns a plain text HTTP response for the AJAX query to examine." He even mentions perhaps the need for JSON: "and from which it will recieve a JSON string containing any errors/advising the servlet what to do next."

Comment: ++; Just an additional suggestion to OP, If it's not a problem for you to include more technologies, please use jQuery/some js framework for your AJAX requests that can encapsulate cross browser behavior. jQuery has a ton of additional benefits as well. And checks like this can be avoided. HTH. --
`if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}else{// code for IE6, IE5  
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}`

Comment: @Gyanapriya yes this is always helpful for cross browser behavior

Answer (score 4):

There's a slightly more direct way of doing it, and it involves @ResponseBody. You can skip the jsp rendering by doing this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/somestring", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getSomeString() {
    return "some string";
}
```

If you want to use something besides a string, you can. The object will get serialized to JSON. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myobject", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
MyObject getSomeString() {
    return new MyObject("blah");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find below some of the observations:

- The `MyServlet` class which is annotated with `@Controller` is not a servlet. It takes care of the controller aspect of MVC design pattern.
- The only servlet that is being used here is `DispatcherServlet`. It is a front facing servlet for all Spring MVC based appliations
- I would suggest renaming the `DispatcherServlet` name, as `MyServlet` name gives a feeling that the servlet is handwritten

And NO, this is not a round about way of implementation. The steps that you have followed is the standard way of working with Spring MVC.

This blog post gives a sample Ajax implementation using Spring MVC:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/

Comment: Sure good point about the servlet name, rather should be called '`MyServletController`.